# Limit script to run only on specific databases

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have databases

```
DEV_a    TST_a    REAL_a
DEV_b    TST_b    REAL_b
DEV_c    TST_c    REAL_c
```

These can be on same server or on different server. Now I'm writing a script/transaction that's relevant only for **DEV_a**, **TST_a** and **REAL_c**.

Is there any way I can limit script to run only on those databases?

I thought this might work:

```
USE [DEV_a]
```

but that would force it to run only on one database, but I have a list.
Is this doable?

Extra question: if it is doable, can I run parts of the script for **DEV_a** and **TST_a** but different part of script for **REAL_c**?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [DB_NAME()](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258270(v=sql.80).aspx), it should be available in SQL 2005.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.SomeTableName
WHERE DB_NAME() IN ('DEV_a', 'TST_a', 'REAL_c')
```

As for the extra question, I think DB_NAME() and [IF...ELSE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933214(v=sql.80).aspx) will work